# Split one record into multiple rows

Tags: sql

Can somebody help me to split records into multiple rows.

My records look like this

```
321517  2013    SEPTEMBER   3   30  286787  321517-2013
321517  2013    SEPTEMBER   2   42  286787  321517-2013
```

I want them to look like this

```
321517  2013    SEPTEMBER   1   30  286787  321517-2013
321517  2013    SEPTEMBER   1   30  286787  321517-2013
321517  2013    SEPTEMBER   1   30  286787  321517-2013
321517  2013    SEPTEMBER   1   42  286787  321517-2013
321517  2013    SEPTEMBER   1   42  286787  321517-2013
```

Comment: what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Which SQL vendor/version? This "inversion" of a group-by count is .. not so simple or universal.

Comment: you can multiply the table if you can "join" with an id generator table. I mean where there are ids starting by 1 incremented by 1 until the max needed number. And instead of simple join you can add a generator_table.id<=original_table.count. In this way this quasi join will be what you would like to get.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables A typo, I did not mean to add that tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the max possible value and then make a recursive CTE to generate rows.

```
;WITH MAX_VALUE AS (
   SELECT MAX(C4) AS VAL FROM Table1
),
TMP_ROWS AS (
    SELECT 1 AS PARENT, 0 AS LVL, 1 AS ID

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        CHILD.PARENT,
        TMP_ROWS.LVL + 1 AS LVL,
        TMP_ROWS.ID
    FROM (SELECT 1 AS PARENT, 1 AS ID, 0 AS NIVEL) AS CHILD
        INNER JOIN TMP_ROWS ON CHILD.PARENT = TMP_ROWS.ID
    WHERE TMP_ROWS.LVL < (SELECT VAL FROM MAX_VALUE)
)
select C1, C2, C3, 1 C4, C5, C6, C7
from Table1 join TMP_ROWS on C4 > TMP_ROWS.LVL
order by C1, C2, C3, C5, C6, C7
```

[Demo (based on previuos reply data)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/295c3/19/0)

*Edit: "ROWS" isnt a good name for a table

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. Please note that this query assumes `maximum value of your 4th Column  is 10`. You can add `more rows to the CTE using a cross join` if you have higher values.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
  select Digit 
  from ( values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) AS t(Digit)
)
select C1, C2, C3, 1 C4, C5, C6, C7
from Table1 join CTE on C4 > Digit
order by C1
```

**[Fiddle demo on sql server 2008](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/295c3/5)**